# Orden de ejecución código android Volley

Tags: android, android-studio, hilos, android-volley

estoy intentando realizar estos pasos en orden:
1-Obtener fecha servidor vía web desde otra clase
2-Manipular dicha respuesta en mi clase principal
Pero me dice que las variables están vacías porque las ejecuta primero
Si en el response pongo un Toast o debugeo, veo el valor correcto, pero si quiero mandarlo para el Main me llega null

Main:

```
fechaServer n = new fechaServer();
        n.obtenerFecha();
        String fecha = n.getFechaServidor();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),fecha ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
```

fechaServer:

```
    public class fechaServer {

private String fechaServidor;

public void obtenerFecha(){
    // Inst the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    String url ="http://sna.getenjoyment.net/date.php";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    fechaServidor = response.substring(0, response.length());
```

//Aquí si en lugar de de guardar en fechaServidor, hago un toast, veo la fecha bien, pero no puedo enviarla al Main, se ejecuta primero vacío

```
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error 319",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);
}

public void setFechaServidor(String fechaServidor) {
    this.fechaServidor = fechaServidor;
}

public String getFechaServidor() {
    return fechaServidor;
}
```

}

Comment: Utiliza los callbhack para retornar la respuesta fuera de Volley, aquí una respuesta del foro que te puede ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/a/28120209/7621631

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba! funcionó a la perfección. Gracias

Comment: Tengo un problema parecido pero con recibir los datos de una pulsera inteligente, que si estoy depurando el código si me devuelve bien los valores, pero si no, no. Los callback me podrían solucionar mi problema? Me podrían ayudar, por favor? Gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

En el activity (MainActivity):

```
private RequestQueue queue;    
private String fechaServidor;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
    //objeto RequestQueue
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    verfecha();

}
```

Luego la función ver fecha:

```
private void verfecha() {
    String url = "http://sna.getenjoyment.net/date.php";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    fechaServidor = response;                                        
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,fechaServidor,
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error 319", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Yo lo probé, y sí almacena el valor en el String para lo que desees luego, claro a mi me sale la fecha 28 de septiembre por la zona horaria (Acá en Lima todavía es 27)

Esta línea de código debe ir donde reciba el argumento de contexto, en cuanto a la declaración del método yo usé Listener en lugar de Response.Listener

```
queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

Espero te haya ayudado.